# Programmatically Update an attribute in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, object

I've looked through all the class documentation for Core Data and I can't find away to programmatically update values in a core data entity. For example, I have a structure similar to this:

```
 id  | title
============
  1  | Foo  
  2  | Bar  
  3  | FooFoo
```

Say that I want to update Bar to BarBar, I can't find any way to do this in any of the documentation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [Apple documentation on using managed objects in Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html) likely has your answer. In short, though, you should be able to do something like this:

```
NSError *saveError;
[bookTwo setTitle:@"BarBar"];
if (![managedObjectContext save:&saveError]) {
    NSLog(@"Saving changes to book book two failed: %@", saveError);
} else {
    // The changes to bookTwo have been persisted.
}
```

(Note: `bookTwo` must be a managed object that is associated with `managedObjectContext` for this example to work.)

Answer (score 43):

In Core Data, an object is an object is an object - the database isn't a thing you throw commands at.

To update something that is persisted, you recreate it as an object, update it, and save it.

```
NSError *error = nil;

//This is your NSManagedObject subclass
Books * aBook = nil;

//Set up to get the thing you want to update
NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyLibrary" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Title=%@",@"Bar"]];

//Ask for it
aBook = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
[request release];

if (error) {
//Handle any errors
}

if (!aBook) {
    //Nothing there to update
}

//Update the object
aBook.Title = @"BarBar";

//Save it
error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
           //Handle any error with the saving of the context
}
```

Comment: Does Core Data auto save? You can call save if you want to force it, but it should auto save AFAIK.

Comment: Not really.  If you let XCode set up a Core Data project in recent releases, the template code includes some calls to the save method of the Managed Object Context in "last chance" places, such as applicationWillTerminate in the app delegate, but that probably is less robust than most apps require.  Calls to save are expensive - the example here after a very minor change is made for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you're thinking in terms of an underlying relational database. Core Data's API is built around model objects, not relational databases.

An entity is a Cocoa object—an instance of `NSManagedObject` or some subclass of that. The entity's attributes are properties of the object. You use key-value coding or, if you implement a subclass, dot syntax or accessor methods to set those properties.

Evan DiBiase's answer shows one correct way to set the property—specifically, an accessor message. Here's dot syntax:

```
bookTwo.title = @"BarBar";
```

And KVC (which you can use with plain old `NSManagedObject`):

```
[bookTwo setValue:@"BarBar" forKey:@"title"];
```

Answer (score 6):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think that all you need to keep in mind is managed objects are really no different than any other Cocoa class. Attributes have accessors and mutators you can use in code, through key value coding or through bindings, only in this case they're generated by Core Data. The only trick is you need to manually declare the generated accessors in your class file (if you have one) for your entity if you want to avoid having to use setValue:ForKey:. The documentation describes this in more detail, but the short answer is that you can select your attributes in the data model designer, and choose **Copy Obj-C 2.0 Method Declarations** from the Design menu.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

        NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"NewWord", nil];


        [object setValue:[temp objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"title"];



        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
```

I think this piece of code will give you the idea ;)